# Values not being returned correctly using session storage and service file

Tags: angular

I have a value that is being stored in sessionStorage. I am trying to get this data and store it in a service file where it can then be used in other parts of my app. I do not want to keep on calling the values directly from my sessionStorage as it will not be used in the future.

Here is my code

app.component.ts

```
sessionStorage.setItem("value", "{"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"openid","profile":{"name":"grumpy","email":"g@g.com","email_verified":true,"phone_number":"0912829343","phone_number_verified":false,"role":"HR Admin"}}");
```

service.ts

```
setStoreData() {
 return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(value));
}
```

When I try to call the service file function I get this in the console

```
store: function () {
        return JSON.parse(value + ":" + src_environments_environment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["environment"].clientId));
}
```

I don't seem to be returning the values correctly. Any ideas why?

Comment: can you show a code which can reproduce the issue?

Comment: ok let me make a stackblitz

Comment: Ok I am closing this, it was a very silly mistake of me not calling the function correctly. Instead of doing this `console.log(storeService.setStoreData());` I done this `console.log(storeService.setStoreData);` I missed the brackets :(